# How to import large mysql dump file into mariadb localhost

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Hi i would like to import a large mysql dump file into localhost maria db...but found this error

[image]

my command is just like so

mysql -u root -p dbname < dumpfile.sql

Answer (score 1):

```
$ mysql --help | grep user
  -u, --user=name     User for login if not current user.
```

So try `mysql -uroot -p dbname < dumpfile.sql` (your screenshot doesn't use -u)